# Maximum Candies You Can Get from Boxes Algorithm - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I'm working on the problem below in JS.

Given n boxes, each box is given in the format [status, candies, keys, containedBoxes] where:

status[i]: an integer which is 1 if box[i] is open and 0 if box[i] is closed.
candies[i]: an integer representing the number of candies in box[i].
keys[i]: an array contains the indices of the boxes you can open with the key in box[i].
containedBoxes[i]: an array contains the indices of the boxes found in box[i].
You will start with some boxes given in initialBoxes array. You can take all the candies in any open box and you can use the keys in it to open new boxes and you also can use the boxes you find in it.

Return the maximum number of candies you can get following the rules above.

Example:

```
Input: status = [1,0,1,0], candies = [7,5,4,100], keys = [[],[],[1],[]], containedBoxes = [[1,2],[3],[],[]], initialBoxes = [0]
Output: 16
Explanation: You will be initially given box 0. You will find 7 candies in it and boxes 1 and 2. Box 1 is closed and you don't have a key for it so you will open box 2. You will find 4 candies and a key to box 1 in box 2.
In box 1, you will find 5 candies and box 3 but you will not find a key to box 3 so box 3 will remain closed.
Total number of candies collected = 7 + 4 + 5 = 16 candy.
```

My solution:

```
var maxCandies = function(status, candies, keys, containedBoxes, initialBoxes) {
    let total = 0;
    let visited = new Set();
    let queue = [];
    let myKeys = new Set();
    
    for(let i=0; i<initialBoxes.length; i++) {
        queue.push(initialBoxes[i]);
        myKeys.add(initialBoxes[i]);
    }
    
    for(let i=0; i<queue.length; i++) {
        const key = keys[queue[i]];
        while(key.length)
            myKeys.add(key.shift());
    }
    
    while(queue.length) {
        const box = queue.shift();
        if(!visited.has(box)) {
            const boxes = containedBoxes[box];
            for(let j=0; j<boxes.length; j++) {
                if(!visited.has(boxes[j]))
                    queue.push(boxes[j]);
            }
            const getkeys = keys[box];
            for(let j=0; j<getkeys.length; j++){
                if(!visited.has(getkeys[j])) {
                    myKeys.add(getkeys[j]);
                    queue.push(getkeys[j]);   
                }
            }
            if(myKeys.has(box) || status[box] === 1) {
                total += candies[box];
                visited.add(box);   
            }
        }
    }
    
    return total;
};
```

It returns the expected result for the example above and some other tests. However, it is failing for the input below.

```
[1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1]
[292,873,110,133,23,240,694,282,404,398,794,657,118,798,613,391,356,601,686,494,219,245,124,638,172,661,2,590,286,648,142,62,755,777,918,63,200,60,934,935,230,266,536,365,651,929,511,295,310,529,745,733,346,979,314,384,808,376,458,50,65,446,700,158,818,916,438,1,53,260,802,563,691,349,4,426,200,346,999,439,877,518,269,997,231,702,89,290,555,474,779,553,40,149,756,299,574,477,429,977,434]
[[63,84,99,73],[9,98,21,34,2,17,26,43],[84,85,100,19,92,33,40,91,66,96,30,3,60,74,72,95,36,29,90,4,98,21,48,56,87,42,97,32,13,93,27,39,81],[67,56,60,74,32,5,59,68,71,45,31,94,83,35,3,38,37,50,92],[81,54,84,63,51,33,80],[51,65,55],[6,57,54,96,90,13,74,23,83,37,64,99,21,2,98,61,19,26,11,29,17,86,28,52,48],[76,36,12,85,67,16,48,8],[],[78,6,53,77,30,41,52,82,35,18,70,32,20,55,58,7,47,88,21,72,16,67,79,90,33,68],[66,0,12,92,99,26,17,44,78,84,8,75,57,97,63,46,43,1,25,88],[54,72,19,62,34,76,28,68,18,75,98,1,87,73,40,57],[56,94,69,14,27,5,21,35],[35,13,29,84,43,97,9,0,19,76,93,48,81],[],[53,86,37,57,99,55,0,44,62,27,45,58,14,81,21,8,33,41,73,64,32,1,51,31,49],[52,62,91,51,72,13,31,34,37,3],[43,38,77,28,85,10,69,83,65,21,5,88,71,64,99,73,37,34,72,35,23,75,47,17],[25,24,61],[82],[100,89,71,16,10,17,90,73,78,22,86,82,48,3,47,0,76,31],[],[1,30,82,87,59,70,28,49,89,91,95,22,43,51,79,35,15,71,18,75,32,58,56],[16,30,95,88,39,56,20,38,27,67,98,0,46,42,92,93,99],[20,99],[33,78,98,9,84,96,20,4,83,18,56,85,70,38,71,10,100,12,14,89,49,60,32,86,17,91,46,8,21,68,44],[13,12,20,24,98,31,9,83,76,92,74,37,88,81,95,47,60,71,61,44,48,80,64,7,49],[58,77,29,63,90,44,49,43,38,23,85],[38,77,45,2,8,81,76,51,44,15,87,31,18,48,30,4,90,100,66,3,47,25,99,10,23,59,36,91,5],[30,98,26],[10,99,78,35,64,56,45,30,15,73,84,51,24,0,79,48,88,33,1,95,97,40,58,42,81],[64],[21,54,23,2,44],[84],[66,9,28,22,0,57,71,11,4,94,30,53,46,39,5,21,92,29,93,100,60,52,62,24,18,74,64],[35,14,95,70,67,30,38,46,74,60,82,28,22,89,57,48,3,29],[41,59,30,79,51,29,92,74,39,93,96,95,24,49,5,4,16,21,97,3,52,83],[32,70,50,57,19,82,49,1,86,37,71,60,77],[76,10,37,35,38,100,97,52,26,16,78,9,65,73,68,12,34,20,43,84,80,81,77,64,63,71,8,61,54],[95,24,9,0,11,74,71,87,78,56,99,61,5,10,55,34,14,80,96,65,35,42,39,67,23,60,58],[14,72,53,8,70,18,11,47,62,71,94,44,9,75,54,39,42,43,85,15,61,55,32,80,37,67,29,0,17,50],[31,22,10,40,34,45,8,63,36,78,83,54,71,87,72,23,41,25,27,60,35,49,14,11,42,92,9,46,56,29,38,77],[51,23,47,14,24,12,42,70,9,87,18,83,95,46,78,71,55,86,48,94,79,31,100,49,89,8,11,25,33],[65,100,38,97,31,77],[51,87,50,10,33,13,82,77,4,9,56,35,78,31,93,84,54,92,38,59,34,36,48,80,95,61,85,28],[34,9,1,85,41,13,52,19,46,50,22,62,69,78,79,49,54,8,83,15],[74,37,86,66,35,31,46,9,36,62,88,57,61,25,65,70,52],[67,33,14,50,49,45,60,37,19,6,54,4,46,64,97,96,52,11,78,38,93,62,51,48,92,10,29,75,16,41,55,58,74],[50,53,65,0,9,82,87,27,75,12,28,86],[64,32,18,60,45,92,33,24,10,58,40,21,9,57,61,90,70,73,28,59],[10,36,48,21,93,64,49,52,46,88,15,87,51,72,95,45,41,76,28,23,98,35],[26,38,64,25,62,56,61,76,81,8,11,88,89,98,100,35,63,34,30,91,49,83,72,96,10,97,80,24,82,13,65],[53,94,2,12,60,52,5,40,23,26,28,34,93,63,85,41],[35,66,1,56,30],[],[61,24,89,44,54,21,11,6,60,20,98,99],[18,55,45,31,36,38,60,95,30,58,48,63,20,34,86,59,8,51,14,100,17,24,3,16,35,73,80,84,94,49,40],[88,13,3,49,58],[88,52,1,40,71,46,10,36,18,4,42,45,91,50,79,58,19,14,0],[],[29,8,33,63,48,50,11,80,49,86,36,54,88,74],[92,60,90,76,80,87,56,71,57,0,48,70,37,38,83],[17,44,13,89,20,75,69,94,66,12,59,62,36,74,6,14,53,2],[55,79,21,13,89,61,74,69,70,76,75,50,66,58,34,93,37,22,88,7,28,51],[73,68,90,84,31,32,22,77,63,85,24,100,3],[50,6,45,15,66,25,79,37,82,41,33],[76,99,26],[40,73,50,84,69,11,19,6,14,12,74,67,97,8,33,7,55,70,63,44,100,25,79,36,76,94,54,53,22,38],[33,49,77,50,56,65,62,81],[47,75,88,20,50,74,23,18,61,69,49,41,58,35,60,99,53,7,77,96],[80,64,14,13,37,33,25,17,38,26,73,4,1,35],[75,16,85,97,31,83,96,82,78,54,73,62,79,55,42,51,43,36,99,26,57,67,24,84,23,47,61,50,63,0,94,66,20],[41,91,23,8,90,27,32,31,64,89,44,97,59,88,11,94,100,78,48,67,84],[46,56,32,71,40,26,83,44,76,73,59,22,24],[39,20,99,12,30,91,89,84,34,45,74,70,100,31,54,75,81,98,35,85,55,4,24,36],[25],[9,16,44,94,82,41,4,39,21,5,73,87,58,91,59,34,47,48,27,78,97,95,96,62,68,69,51,84],[27,20,40,28,77],[30],[76,31,91,36,62,7,78,23,63,68,86,26,8,39,64,85,54,42,29,18,17,47],[53,99,51],[27,80,37,92,40,9,56,52,34,67,10,33,48,73,26,59,83,65,64,4,3,68,85,69,63],[11,57,87,89,21,74,17,61,51,80,26,70,39,9,36,75,63,85,100,18,15,96,90,47,84],[66,74,84,5,13,0,57,23,8],[95,43,8,27,85,96,47,53,48,3,41,86,32,70,12,15,82,6,62,81,4,97,40,13,23,24,59,26,98,71,35],[35,29,64,85,63,50,67,43,54,39,94,65,87],[86,90,70,100,72,76,48,37,80,34],[44,1,25,14,41,9,72,32,19,92,100,55,0,30,76,26,99,96,16,21,11,70,74,49,65,59,27,94,87,62,3],[72,28,41,81,58,84,8,39,51,100,54,71,70,36,94,47,65,97,32,85,30,68,87,26,75,95],[86,52,26,100,0,11,19,20,82,21,88,84,9,65],[71,30,18,43,50,76,87,19],[18,64,20,80,91,0,45,97,78,98,31,23,38,8,17,32,9,55,86,44,40,77,85,14,11,81,22,42,89,63,7,60,13],[37,58,12,75,31,33,25,11,26,88,53,91,93,85,52,81,10,43,51,20,35,45,3],[88,26,23,64,56,5,21,16,15,39],[88,37,85,2,61,100,24,93,23,78,46,54,36,74,84,47,58,77,28],[],[15,23,54,73,21,33,76,96,89,12,48,10,9,92,61,59,65,42,29,37,86,27,20],[76,93,3,37,27,65,20,34,11,99,98,28,67,5,13,80,42,64,61,43,79,23,29],[41,54,81,17,90,23,75,4,62,46,52,57],[20,52,8,58,87,48,6,89,93],[49,9,34,28,41,69,87,50,54,83,96,44,5,12,86,76,92,2,19,48,4,55,85,10,25,1,78,15,61,74]]
[[],[],[41],[94],[],[63],[29],[46],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[42,77],[],[],[],[],[64],[86],[],[8,15],[24],[],[100],[],[],[],[],[56],[],[84],[],[],[71],[],[23,83],[],[40],[],[],[20],[],[13,57],[51],[3,69],[],[68],[49],[],[28],[],[],[88],[],[52],[],[],[],[36],[14,55],[],[2],[95],[],[],[],[33],[],[93],[59],[],[74],[22],[47],[],[],[45],[35],[],[],[],[],[32],[],[1],[61],[],[],[],[44],[],[],[],[],[],[48],[],[85,96]]
[0,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,16,17,18,19,21,25,26,27,30,31,34,37,38,39,43,50,53,54,58,60,62,65,66,67,70,72,73,75,76,78,79,80,81,82,87,89,90,91,92,97,98,99]
```

The expected result is `45940`. My solution is returning `46346`. Does anyone know why it is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's wrong with your method, but this one seems to work. I didn't use a "visited" structure, but I implemented a hash with counts for still unopened boxes, as well as pushing to the stack any box that can be opened (after the initial) so that the procedure there can be reused. (By the way, `status` seems to be a reserved variable sometimes so I renamed it to `_status`.)

```js
function f(_status, candies, keys, containedBoxes, initialBoxes){
  const closed = {};
  const myKeys = new Set();
  const stack = initialBoxes.map(x => [x, 1]);
  let result = 0;

  while (stack.length){
    const [box, boxCount] = stack.pop();

    // We can open the box
    if (myKeys.has(box) || _status[box]){
      // Get candies
      result += boxCount * candies[box];

      // Add boxes
      for (let newBox of containedBoxes[box]){
        if (myKeys.has(box) || _status[newBox])
          stack.push([newBox, 1])
        else
          closed[newBox] = -~closed[newBox];
      }

      // Get keys
      for (let newKey of keys[box]){
        myKeys.add(newKey);

        // Maybe use a new key
        if (closed[newKey]){
          stack.push([newKey, closed[newKey]]);
          delete closed[newKey];
        }
      }
      
    // We cannot open the box
    } else {
      closed[box] = -~closed[box];
    }
  }

  return result;
}


var _status = [1,0,1,0];
var candies = [7,5,4,100];
var keys = [[],[],[1],[]];
var containedBoxes = [[1,2],[3],[],[]];
var initialBoxes = [0]; // 16

console.log(f(_status, candies, keys, containedBoxes, initialBoxes));

var args = [
  [1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1],

  [292,873,110,133,23,240,694,282,404,398,794,657,118,798,613,391,356,601,686,494,219,245,124,638,172,661,2,590,286,648,142,62,755,777,918,63,200,60,934,935,230,266,536,365,651,929,511,295,310,529,745,733,346,979,314,384,808,376,458,50,65,446,700,158,818,916,438,1,53,260,802,563,691,349,4,426,200,346,999,439,877,518,269,997,231,702,89,290,555,474,779,553,40,149,756,299,574,477,429,977,434],

  [[63,84,99,73],[9,98,21,34,2,17,26,43],[84,85,100,19,92,33,40,91,66,96,30,3,60,74,72,95,36,29,90,4,98,21,48,56,87,42,97,32,13,93,27,39,81],[67,56,60,74,32,5,59,68,71,45,31,94,83,35,3,38,37,50,92],[81,54,84,63,51,33,80],[51,65,55],[6,57,54,96,90,13,74,23,83,37,64,99,21,2,98,61,19,26,11,29,17,86,28,52,48],[76,36,12,85,67,16,48,8],[],[78,6,53,77,30,41,52,82,35,18,70,32,20,55,58,7,47,88,21,72,16,67,79,90,33,68],[66,0,12,92,99,26,17,44,78,84,8,75,57,97,63,46,43,1,25,88],[54,72,19,62,34,76,28,68,18,75,98,1,87,73,40,57],[56,94,69,14,27,5,21,35],[35,13,29,84,43,97,9,0,19,76,93,48,81],[],[53,86,37,57,99,55,0,44,62,27,45,58,14,81,21,8,33,41,73,64,32,1,51,31,49],[52,62,91,51,72,13,31,34,37,3],[43,38,77,28,85,10,69,83,65,21,5,88,71,64,99,73,37,34,72,35,23,75,47,17],[25,24,61],[82],[100,89,71,16,10,17,90,73,78,22,86,82,48,3,47,0,76,31],[],[1,30,82,87,59,70,28,49,89,91,95,22,43,51,79,35,15,71,18,75,32,58,56],[16,30,95,88,39,56,20,38,27,67,98,0,46,42,92,93,99],[20,99],[33,78,98,9,84,96,20,4,83,18,56,85,70,38,71,10,100,12,14,89,49,60,32,86,17,91,46,8,21,68,44],[13,12,20,24,98,31,9,83,76,92,74,37,88,81,95,47,60,71,61,44,48,80,64,7,49],[58,77,29,63,90,44,49,43,38,23,85],[38,77,45,2,8,81,76,51,44,15,87,31,18,48,30,4,90,100,66,3,47,25,99,10,23,59,36,91,5],[30,98,26],[10,99,78,35,64,56,45,30,15,73,84,51,24,0,79,48,88,33,1,95,97,40,58,42,81],[64],[21,54,23,2,44],[84],[66,9,28,22,0,57,71,11,4,94,30,53,46,39,5,21,92,29,93,100,60,52,62,24,18,74,64],[35,14,95,70,67,30,38,46,74,60,82,28,22,89,57,48,3,29],[41,59,30,79,51,29,92,74,39,93,96,95,24,49,5,4,16,21,97,3,52,83],[32,70,50,57,19,82,49,1,86,37,71,60,77],[76,10,37,35,38,100,97,52,26,16,78,9,65,73,68,12,34,20,43,84,80,81,77,64,63,71,8,61,54],[95,24,9,0,11,74,71,87,78,56,99,61,5,10,55,34,14,80,96,65,35,42,39,67,23,60,58],[14,72,53,8,70,18,11,47,62,71,94,44,9,75,54,39,42,43,85,15,61,55,32,80,37,67,29,0,17,50],[31,22,10,40,34,45,8,63,36,78,83,54,71,87,72,23,41,25,27,60,35,49,14,11,42,92,9,46,56,29,38,77],[51,23,47,14,24,12,42,70,9,87,18,83,95,46,78,71,55,86,48,94,79,31,100,49,89,8,11,25,33],[65,100,38,97,31,77],[51,87,50,10,33,13,82,77,4,9,56,35,78,31,93,84,54,92,38,59,34,36,48,80,95,61,85,28],[34,9,1,85,41,13,52,19,46,50,22,62,69,78,79,49,54,8,83,15],[74,37,86,66,35,31,46,9,36,62,88,57,61,25,65,70,52],[67,33,14,50,49,45,60,37,19,6,54,4,46,64,97,96,52,11,78,38,93,62,51,48,92,10,29,75,16,41,55,58,74],[50,53,65,0,9,82,87,27,75,12,28,86],[64,32,18,60,45,92,33,24,10,58,40,21,9,57,61,90,70,73,28,59],[10,36,48,21,93,64,49,52,46,88,15,87,51,72,95,45,41,76,28,23,98,35],[26,38,64,25,62,56,61,76,81,8,11,88,89,98,100,35,63,34,30,91,49,83,72,96,10,97,80,24,82,13,65],[53,94,2,12,60,52,5,40,23,26,28,34,93,63,85,41],[35,66,1,56,30],[],[61,24,89,44,54,21,11,6,60,20,98,99],[18,55,45,31,36,38,60,95,30,58,48,63,20,34,86,59,8,51,14,100,17,24,3,16,35,73,80,84,94,49,40],[88,13,3,49,58],[88,52,1,40,71,46,10,36,18,4,42,45,91,50,79,58,19,14,0],[],[29,8,33,63,48,50,11,80,49,86,36,54,88,74],[92,60,90,76,80,87,56,71,57,0,48,70,37,38,83],[17,44,13,89,20,75,69,94,66,12,59,62,36,74,6,14,53,2],[55,79,21,13,89,61,74,69,70,76,75,50,66,58,34,93,37,22,88,7,28,51],[73,68,90,84,31,32,22,77,63,85,24,100,3],[50,6,45,15,66,25,79,37,82,41,33],[76,99,26],[40,73,50,84,69,11,19,6,14,12,74,67,97,8,33,7,55,70,63,44,100,25,79,36,76,94,54,53,22,38],[33,49,77,50,56,65,62,81],[47,75,88,20,50,74,23,18,61,69,49,41,58,35,60,99,53,7,77,96],[80,64,14,13,37,33,25,17,38,26,73,4,1,35],[75,16,85,97,31,83,96,82,78,54,73,62,79,55,42,51,43,36,99,26,57,67,24,84,23,47,61,50,63,0,94,66,20],[41,91,23,8,90,27,32,31,64,89,44,97,59,88,11,94,100,78,48,67,84],[46,56,32,71,40,26,83,44,76,73,59,22,24],[39,20,99,12,30,91,89,84,34,45,74,70,100,31,54,75,81,98,35,85,55,4,24,36],[25],[9,16,44,94,82,41,4,39,21,5,73,87,58,91,59,34,47,48,27,78,97,95,96,62,68,69,51,84],[27,20,40,28,77],[30],[76,31,91,36,62,7,78,23,63,68,86,26,8,39,64,85,54,42,29,18,17,47],[53,99,51],[27,80,37,92,40,9,56,52,34,67,10,33,48,73,26,59,83,65,64,4,3,68,85,69,63],[11,57,87,89,21,74,17,61,51,80,26,70,39,9,36,75,63,85,100,18,15,96,90,47,84],[66,74,84,5,13,0,57,23,8],[95,43,8,27,85,96,47,53,48,3,41,86,32,70,12,15,82,6,62,81,4,97,40,13,23,24,59,26,98,71,35],[35,29,64,85,63,50,67,43,54,39,94,65,87],[86,90,70,100,72,76,48,37,80,34],[44,1,25,14,41,9,72,32,19,92,100,55,0,30,76,26,99,96,16,21,11,70,74,49,65,59,27,94,87,62,3],[72,28,41,81,58,84,8,39,51,100,54,71,70,36,94,47,65,97,32,85,30,68,87,26,75,95],[86,52,26,100,0,11,19,20,82,21,88,84,9,65],[71,30,18,43,50,76,87,19],[18,64,20,80,91,0,45,97,78,98,31,23,38,8,17,32,9,55,86,44,40,77,85,14,11,81,22,42,89,63,7,60,13],[37,58,12,75,31,33,25,11,26,88,53,91,93,85,52,81,10,43,51,20,35,45,3],[88,26,23,64,56,5,21,16,15,39],[88,37,85,2,61,100,24,93,23,78,46,54,36,74,84,47,58,77,28],[],[15,23,54,73,21,33,76,96,89,12,48,10,9,92,61,59,65,42,29,37,86,27,20],[76,93,3,37,27,65,20,34,11,99,98,28,67,5,13,80,42,64,61,43,79,23,29],[41,54,81,17,90,23,75,4,62,46,52,57],[20,52,8,58,87,48,6,89,93],[49,9,34,28,41,69,87,50,54,83,96,44,5,12,86,76,92,2,19,48,4,55,85,10,25,1,78,15,61,74]],

  [[],[],[41],[94],[],[63],[29],[46],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[42,77],[],[],[],[],[64],[86],[],[8,15],[24],[],[100],[],[],[],[],[56],[],[84],[],[],[71],[],[23,83],[],[40],[],[],[20],[],[13,57],[51],[3,69],[],[68],[49],[],[28],[],[],[88],[],[52],[],[],[],[36],[14,55],[],[2],[95],[],[],[],[33],[],[93],[59],[],[74],[22],[47],[],[],[45],[35],[],[],[],[],[32],[],[1],[61],[],[],[],[44],[],[],[],[],[],[48],[],[85,96]],

  [0,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,16,17,18,19,21,25,26,27,30,31,34,37,38,39,43,50,53,54,58,60,62,65,66,67,70,72,73,75,76,78,79,80,81,82,87,89,90,91,92,97,98,99]
];

console.log(f(...args));
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain what this line ```-~closed[newBox]``` does?

Comment: @myTest532myTest532 sure. `-~closed[newBox]` (notice the minus sign) increments the value, `closed[newBox]`, by 1 or sets it to 1 if the value is falsy.

Answer (score 0):

Your design is too difficult to maintain. It's time for you to learn about `class`es or `constructors`. I prefer the later due to the guarantee of private variables.

```js
function CandyBox(candyCount = 0, opened = false, boxKeys = null){
  this.candyCount = candyCount; this.boxes = [];
  this.opened = opened ? true : false;
  this.boxKeys = boxKeys instanceof Array ? boxKeys : [];
  const boxKey = candyBox=>{
    return this.boxKeys.indexOf(candyBox);
  }
  this.addKey = function(){;
    for(let o of arguments){
      if(o !== this && boxKey(o) === -1)this.boxKeys.push(o);
    }
    return this;
  }
  this.removeKey = function(){
    let k;
    for(let o of arguments){
      k = boxKey(o);
      if(k !== -1)this.boxKeys.splice(k, 1);
    }
    return this;
  }
  this.addBox = function(){
    for(let o of arguments){
      if(o !== this && boxKey(o) === -1)this.boxes.push(o);
    }
    return this;
  }
  this.removeBox = function(){
    let k;
    for(let o of arguments){
      k = boxKey(o);
      if(k !== -1)this.boxes.splice(k, 1);
    }
    return this;
  }
  this.countCandy = (unlock = false)=>{
    if(!this.opened && !unlock){
      return 0;
    }
    let c = this.candyCount;
    for(let o of this.boxKeys){
      c += o.countCandy(true);
    }
    return c;
  }
}
const box1 = new CandyBox(7, true), box2 = new CandyBox(5), box3 = new CandyBox(4, true), box4 = new CandyBox(100);
box1.addBox(box2, box3); box2.addBox(box4); box3.addKey(box2);
const candyBoxes = [box1, box2, box3, box4];
let candyCount = 0;
for(let o of candyBoxes){
  candyCount += o.countCandy();
}
console.log(candyCount);
```

Object Oriented Programming is the way to go.

Comment: Can you please add a method or function that can take the input parameters provided in the question description? I'd like to test performance of this code with the larger input.

Comment: Just use the methods I have provided to `.addBox` or `.addKey` and do it yourself.